# How can I remove a screwdriver bit that is stuck in the chuck of my impact driver?

Tags: tools

Does anyone know how to release this little screw driver bit from the chuck? Pulling the chuck out to release doesn't work and I can't grab it with pliers.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Yes I know...I should have used a bit extender.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, you're going to have to pull the black knurled collar forward to release the ball detent holding the bit into the impact driver.

Were it me, I'd look for a powerful magnet to touch the bit to while I pull the collar forward.

Answer (score 0):

While holding the chuck's retention collar in the release position and with the bit pointed downward...

- Tap on the chuck with another metal tool.
- Install a matching screw onto the bit and use it to turn and jiggle the bit, pulling gently.
- Bond a screw to the bit with super glue and pull it out.
- Heat the inner chuck part with a flame to expand the bore.